# searching a json file

Tags: php, json

I have a file test.json see below

```
[
 {
   "ID": "01AD003",
   "Name": "ST. FRANCIS RIVER AT OUTLET OF GLASIER LAKE",
   "Latitude": 47.20661,
   "Longitude": -68.95694,
   "Prov": "NB",
   "Timezone": "UTC-04:00"
 },
 {
   "ID": "01AD004",
   "Name": "SAINT JOHN RIVER AT EDMUNDSTON",
   "Latitude": 47.36078,
   "Longitude": -68.32489,
   "Prov": "NB",
   "Timezone": "UTC-04:00"
 },
 {
   "ID": "01AF002",
   "Name": "SAINT JOHN RIVER AT GRAND FALLS",
   "Latitude": 47.03889,
   "Longitude": -67.73972,
   "Prov": "NB",
   "Timezone": "UTC-04:00"
 }
]
```

I am trying to search this file based on the ID element and return the Latitude and Longitude using php

I have tried adding a string local:

```
function getLatLong($id) 
{

    $str = file_get_contents("./hydrometric_StationList.json");

    $json = json_decode($str);
    foreach($json->local as $item)
    {
        if($item->ID == $id)
        {
            return $item->Latitude.",".$item.Latitude;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `true` as the second parameter on `json_decode` to decode it as assositive array instead of an object. You can do a simple `foreach` loop like:

```
function getLatLong($id) 
{

    $str = file_get_contents("./hydrometric_StationList.json");
    $json = json_decode($str, true);

    foreach($json as $item)
    {
        if($item['ID'] == $id)
        {
            return $item['Latitude'].",".$item['Latitude'];
        }
    }
}
```

`echo  getLatLong("01AF002");` will result to: `47.03889,47.03889`

Comment: There is no need to change it to an associative array, objects will still work (with a few corrections).

Comment: Sure. But there is nothing wrong suggesting associative array. That is easier to understand especially for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of mistakes in your code.

In your `foreach()` you have `$json->local`, but `local` isn't in the data.  Just remove the `->local` part.

In the `return` you have `$item.Latitude`, which both shouldn't be a `.` and is returning the latitude again, so change this to `$item->Longitude`...

```
function getLatLong($id) 
{

    $str = file_get_contents("./hydrometric_StationList.json");

    $json = json_decode($str);
    foreach($json->local as $item)
    {
        if($item->ID == $id)
        {
            return $item->Latitude.",".$item->Longitude;
        }
    }

}
```